# How to get Django to reference the name instead of the id/pk

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a tutoring API using Python and Django. I want the Tutor Model to show all the tutees (yes, that is a word) and the tutee to show the tutor. Right now, it works correctly but it references the id/pk of the model so I really don't know who or what it refers to.

GET a tutee :

```
{
"id": 1
"full_name": "First Last",
"email": "email@emailprovidercom",
"tutor": 1,
"subjects": "SubjectX"
}
```

As you can see, the tutor is a number instead of a name.

GET a tutor:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "full_name": "First Last",
    "email": "name.name@emailprovider.com",
    "notes": "XXXXX XX XX X X  X X X  X XXXXXX XX X X  X X ",
    "tutees": [
        1
    ]
}
```

The same thing happens here.

I am using Django Rest Framework.

My models

```
class Tutor(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    notes = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name


class Tutee(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(Tutor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tutees")
    subjects = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

My Serializers

```
class TutorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tutor
        fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'email', 'notes', 'tutees']


class TuteeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tutee
        fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'email', "tutor", "subjects"]
```

My Viewsets

```
class TutorAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tutor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TutorSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = "full_name"


class TuteeAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tutee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TuteeSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = "full_name"
```

If you need more, please comment and I will edit my question! Even if you just mark it as duplicate, that would be helpful.

Comment: The solution here may be a nested serializer. Getting the name of the tutor is also not meaningful for you as this might not be unique. Id/Pk is still meaningful as it denotes one tutor in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help if You wanna get only string representation

```
class TuteeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tutor = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Tutee
        fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'email', "tutor", "subjects"]
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: This worked for the other serializer. (Tutor) not tutee.

Comment: I removed many=True for the Tutee and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the pk or name might not be meaningful to you. You should get both or even more fields. Nest serializer might be a good solution here based on your requirements.

You might be looking at something like this:

```py
class TutorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tutor
        fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'email',]


class TuteeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tutor_info = TutorSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Tutee
        fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'email', "tutor_info", "subjects"]
```

Comment: I removed the many=True and it worked. How would I only get the name, email, etc from it instead of everything. Right now, I also get the Tutors tutees back and that is kinda repetetive.

Comment: Never mind, I made some edits to the other person's answer and it works.

Comment: You can edit the `TutorSerializer` to just include `id` and `name`. I think you did not notice the changes I did to `TutorSerializer`. Please have a look at that closely.